# Cambio de color Knob JQuery en base al valor

Tags: jquery

Quiero mostrar unos resultados mediante la librería JQuery-knob.js , los resultados los obtengo bien y dibujo el knob correctamente, el problema es que quiero que cambie de color en base al valor que reciba, y no me realiza el cambio de color si el valor es mayor, este es mi código:

```
$('.dial').knob({
'min':0,
'max':50,
'width':250,
'height': 250,
draw: function () {
     v=parseInt(document.getElementById('circle').value);
          //console.log(v);
          if (v <=6 ) {
              this.o.fgColor='#59BD05';
              $("#circle").css("color", "#59BD05");
             
          }
          if (v > 6 ) {
              this.o.fgColor='#FE9D08';
              $("#circle").css("color", "#FE9D08");
              
          }
          if (v > 30 ) {
              this.o.fgColor='#F33A08';
              $("#circle").css("color", "#F33A08");
              
          }
        // $(this.i).val(this.cv + 'µg/m"<sup>3</sup>"') 
    },
    release: function (value) {
        
    }
});
```

Y aquí se puede apreciar como no me cambia el color de los knobs, y además tampoco me establece el color del valor numérico, los input son readonly, no quiero poder cambiar los datos solo mostrarlos mediante el knob ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que no has definido la variable `v`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$('.dial').knob({
  'min': 0,
  'max': 50,
  'width': 250,
  'height': 250,
  'draw': function() {
    let v = parseInt(this.i[0].value);
    if (v <= 6) this.o.fgColor = '#59BD05';
    else if (v <= 30) this.o.fgColor = '#FE9D08';
    else this.o.fgColor = '#F33A08';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Knob/1.2.13/jquery.knob.min.js" integrity="sha512-NhRZzPdzMOMf005Xmd4JonwPftz4Pe99mRVcFeRDcdCtfjv46zPIi/7ZKScbpHD/V0HB1Eb+ZWigMqw94VUVaw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text" value="5" class="dial">
```